# ¿Como poder mostrar un solo registro de lo que devuelve una lista en java?

Tags: java, jsf, lista

Tengo el siguiente codigo, el cual manda a llamar un query que me regresa una lista y en consola me arroja lo suiente

```
incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(cvePersona, annio, 1);

    for (IncidenciaAnioMesDet incidencia : incidenciaAnioMesDet) {

        if (incidencia.getDia() != null && incidencia.getIncidencias() != null && incidencia.getIncidencias().getCveIdIncidencia() != null) {
            System.out.println("PRUEBA\n" + " DIA-" + incidencia.getDia() + " INCIDENCIA-" + incidencia.getIncidencias().getCveIdIncidencia());


        }

    }
```

```html
PRUEBA
 DIA-4 INCIDENCIA-1

PRUEBA
 DIA-7 INCIDENCIA-11

PRUEBA
 DIA-1 INCIDENCIA-33

PRUEBA
 DIA-2 INCIDENCIA-99

PRUEBA
 DIA-6 INCIDENCIA-10

PRUEBA
 DIA-5 INCIDENCIA-1
```

lo que hago es pasar esa info a una tabla, de la siguiente manera

```html
<p:dataTable id="consultaIncidencia" styleClass="columns consultaIncidencia" var="incidenciaDet" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnioMesDet}" selection="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnio}">
  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <p:column headerText="RFC" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <p:column headerText="Nombre" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <p:column headerText="Clave" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <ui:repeat value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listDias}" var="dia">
        <p:column headerText="#{dia}" />
      </ui:repeat>

    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.persona.rfc}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.persona.nombre} #{incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.persona.primerApellido} #{incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.persona.segundoApellido}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.persona.puesto}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:columns value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listDias}" var="dia" styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.llenaTabla(incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.persona.cveIdPersona, incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.anio, incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.mes, dia)}" />
  </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

y me pinta los datos asi, ejemplo con lo que pinta en consola, en el dia 1 esta la incidencia 33

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el detalle es que me repite n veces la misma info, lo que quiero hacer es tener un solo renglon , xq lo demas es repetido, como le puedo hacer para que solo aparezca un solo renglon  en mi tabla?

Comment: Pon mas información la lista incidenciaAnioMesDet  es la que regresas, ya imprimiste o verificaste lo que recuperar la consulta como tal, por que si lo que quieres regresar es lo que estas imprimiendo en el for usa otra lista para agregar esos registros que cumplen tu condición del if

Comment: Falta información, en el for que imprimiste por consola solo muestras los dias de una sola persona? Que persona? Cual es el contenido del metodo `llenaTabla` ?

Comment: @Klaimmore, el for que imprimo en consola solo muestra los dias  e incidencias de una sola persona, que es el id=1

Comment: Te recomiendo que en vez de imprimir, en tu prueba, el día de la incidencia y el id de esta, imprimas los nombres de las personas. Estoy casi seguro que se repiten las personas en la lista. En caso de no ser así, por favor comparte la impresión por consola para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @E.Betanzos,  tengo este sout para imprimir el nombre de la persona,  System.out.println("PRUEBA\n" + " DIA-" + incidencia.getDia() + " INCIDENCIA-" + incidencia.getIncidencias().getCveIdIncidencia() +"NOMBRE-" +incidencia.getIncidenciaAnioMes().getPersona().getNombre());  y si, es la misma persona, osea mi busqueda es por id,que corresponde a esa misma persona, solo no quiero mostrar en la tabla las n veces

Comment: @E.Betanzos, imprime lo siguiente:  DIA-3 INCIDENCIA-1NOMBRE-BERTHA NOEMI

PRUEBA
 DIA-4 INCIDENCIA-99 NOMBRE-BERTHA NOEMI

PRUEBA
 DIA-5 INCIDENCIA-99NOMBRE-BERTHA NOEMI

PRUEBA
 DIA-8 INCIDENCIA-1NOMBRE-BERTHA NOEMI

Comment: Te das cuenta de lo que ocurre?? Tienes un listado donde se repite la misma persona, por eso en tu table de JSF aparece varias veces, porque así está en la colección. Si lo que quieres es que solo aparezca una fila por cada persona, con toda su información, vas a tener que implementar algún mecanismo que tome ese listado y haga una compilación de la información de cada persona.

Answer (score 0):

La iteracion tiene que ser por persona para pintar los rows:

```
#{incidenciaDet.incidenciaAnioMes.persona}
```

en ves de

```
#{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnioMesDet}
```

como iteras los dias es por eso que se repite la fila **n** veces, veo que que accedes a persona a traves del objeto incidencia, ¿ todas las incidencias buscadas por cvePersona siempre contendran la misma persona ? de ser asi tu relacion entre incidencia-persona no es la correcta ya que se repite la misma persona para cada incidencia, la relacion deberia ser **1 persona --> 1 o muchas incidencias**.

Independientemente de que revises el tema de tus relaciones, mi solucion a tu codigo actual seria(suponiendo que tienes el objeto Persona porque de ahi sacas su cvePersona):

```
Persona persona = tuMetodoParaBuscarPersona(x);
cvePersona = persona.cvePersona;
incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(cvePersona, annio, 1);
int[] arrayIncidenciasMes = new int[incidenciaAnioMesDet + 1];

public void armarArregloIncidenciasMes() {
    //El arreglo sera tu mes, cada posicion equivale a cada dia: [0] -> dia 0, [1] -> dia 1
    for (int i=1; i <= arrayIncidenciasMes; i++) {
        arrayIncidenciasMes[i] = 0; //Inicializas con cero numero de incidencias el dia

        //Buscas en tu lista si hay alguna incidencia con ese dia
        for(Incidencia incidencia : incidenciaAnioMesDet) {
            if (i == incidencia.getDay()) { //Dia 1 arrayIncidenciasMes[1]
                arrayIncidenciasMes[i] = incidencia.getCveIdIncidencia(); //[i]=CveIdIncidencia
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

<p:dataTable id="consultaIncidencia" styleClass="columns consultaIncidencia" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" selection="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnio}">
  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <p:column headerText="RFC" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <p:column headerText="Nombre" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <p:column headerText="Clave" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <ui:repeat value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listDias}" var="dia">
        <p:column headerText="#{dia}" />
      </ui:repeat>

    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>

  <p:row>
      <p:column styleClass="columns">
        <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.persona.rfc}" />
      </p:column>
  </p:row>
  <p:row>
      <p:column styleClass="columns">
        <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.persona.nombre} #{RegistroAccesoComponent.persona.primerApellido} #{RegistroAccesoComponent.persona.segundoApellido}" />
      </p:column>
  </p:row>
  <p:row>
      <p:column styleClass="columns">
        <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.persona.puesto}" />
      </p:column>
  </p:row>
  <p:row>
      <p:columns value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listDias}" var="dia" styleClass="columns">
        <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.arrayIncidenciasMes[dia]}" />
      </p:columns>
  </p:row>
</p:dataTable>
```

Nota: meto las etiquetas **p:row** para pintar manualmente una sola fila para la persona ya que quitamos la propiedad de la iteracion del dataTable.

Saludos.